# Load Image for cropping from Google Photos Gallery

Tags: android, google-plus, crop, photos

Is it possible to crop an image from Google Photos? The app I'm creating allows the user to select an image and crop it. When selecting an image the user is asked to select an app to complete the action(Album, Google Photos, etc) Selecting and cropping an image from album works perfectly, but selecting one from Google Photos crashes with no error. Apps like BBM and WhatsApp allows cropping from Photos to upload a profile picture. I want to do something similar.

**Here's my Code:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_FILE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_FROM_FILE:
    mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 650);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 650);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        Intent i = new Intent(intent);
        ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
        i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
    }
    break;
    case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
      Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
      if (extras != null) {
         Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
         mImageView.setBackgroundColor(0);
      }
      File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
      if (f.exists()) f.delete();
      break;
    }
}
```

**P.S:** This is for KitKat and Higher(API19)

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are [several image cropping libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) available; please use one.

Comment: Ah okay, I get it. I'll use a library. Thanks for the links. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CROP_PIC_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data != null) {

            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            }
            else {
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(bitmap!=null) billImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem may result because, above android 5.0 the Crop function returns an **URI** in **onActivityResult** instead of a **bitmap**, so you have to handle ti accordingly.

Anyway, I think is better to use a library like https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper, that is optimized and handles different cases.